# Node selenium-webdriver "Error: Timed out waiting for the WebDriver server at"

Tags: node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver

While following the instructions in the ['Getting Started' section of 
the WebDriverJs documentation](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/WebDriverJs#Getting_Started) and after running this snippet from their site:

```
var driver = new webdriver.Builder().
   withCapabilities(webdriver.Capabilities.chrome()).
   build();

driver.get('http://www.google.com');
driver.findElement(webdriver.By.name('q')).sendKeys('webdriver');
driver.findElement(webdriver.By.name('btnG')).click();
driver.wait(function() {
 return driver.getTitle().then(function(title) {
   return title === 'webdriver - Google Search';
 });
}, 1000);

driver.quit();
```

I'm getting this error:

```
Error: Timed out waiting for the WebDriver server at http://XXX.XXX.X.XXX:60065/
    at <anonymous>
    at <anonymous>
    at <anonymous>
    at <anonymous>
    at <anonymous>
    at <anonymous>
    at <anonymous>
    at <anonymous>
    at <anonymous>
    at <anonymous>
==== async task ====
WebDriver.createSession()
```

I'm running OSX Mavericks using the mac32 version of ChromeDriver found [here](http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.10/). The `chromedriver` executable is in my `/usr/local/bin` directory, and is accessible on my `path`.

One thing I notice is that when I run `chromedriver` from the command line, it runs on port `9515`, while the node code is looking for it on `60065`. However, there shouldn't be any extra configuration required for just running with the `chromedriver`.

Would anyone have any ideas on why I'm getting this error?

Comment: possible duplicate of [protractor stand alone selenium fails: Error: Timed out waiting for the WebDriver server at](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20555953/protractor-stand-alone-selenium-fails-error-timed-out-waiting-for-the-webdrive)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was having this exact issue today and near as I can tell it's a bug with the current version of the `selenium-webdriver` package (2.41.0).

[There is a bug filed with the Selenium project](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=7300) but I don't think the fix has made its way onto npm yet.

Downgrading to version 2.9.248307 of Chromedriver worked for me.

Comment: Same for me 2.10 did not work, 2.9 works perfectly. Thanks guys.

Comment: Putting "directConnect: true" inside protractor config solved issue to me

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Andrej Kaurin comment:

You can set
`directConnnect: true`
in your protractor configuration.

When this is set, protractor connects directly with browser driver and selenium is not needed.

More details: https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/server-setup.md#connecting-directly-to-browser-drivers

Answer (score 0):

For me what worked was being on version `78.0.33904.70` of ChromeDriver and then version of Chrome Browser `78.0.3904.87`

Here is the link to get Chrome Driver:
http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=78.0.3904.70/

How to check what version of chrome you have: https://support.chall.com/hc/en-us/articles/200336349-How-do-I-determine-what-version-of-Google-Chrome-I-m-using-

Answer (score 0):

I had this error when using **new firefox.Service Builder('/path/to/geckodriver')**, this error disappeared when I added the path to geckodriver to the variable **$PATH**.