# Timed out error on starting Webdriver server when connected to network via VPN

Tags: selenium-webdriver, protractor, vpn

In my protractor config file, I had this line, seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub'. On running Protractor I was getting an error "ECONNREFUSED connect ECONNREFUSED". After going through lot of other existing issues and solutions, I removed "seleniumAddress" property. That resolved the issue. Selenium standalone server gets started. "Selenium standalone server started at http://192.168.1.156:64477/wd/hub"

But when I turn on the VPN, then I get an error "Error: Timed out waiting for the WebDriver server at http://192.168.1.156:63199/wd/hub", which I have been not able to resolve.

I am on a HP laptop which has Windows 7 Professional and I am using Cisco VPN.

Answer (score 0):

(Hi, so I can't comment yet (low rep)...)

Could you try running `webdriver-manager start` before running protractor? It will run in the address `http://localhost:4444/wd/hub` which is the `seleniumAddress` referred to in the protractor config. Does that change anything?

This might be related (VPN-workaround): [protractor stand alone selenium fails: Error: Timed out waiting for the WebDriver server at](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23544850/2760194)

Answer (score 0):

Check the settings of the firewall that stays between Selenium standalone server (which might run also on your local host) and your working station (usually your localhost).

In my case (running on local Linux station) I had a very restrictive iptables firewall rules such that the WebDriver process launched on localhost could not access the Selenium standalone server which also run on localhost at whatever TCP port.

Just try to turn it off and check if that is the case ; then accommodate your firewall settings such that the respective connection passes your firewall rules.

If you want your scripts communicate directly with the Firefox|Chrome Driver (bypassing the Selenium server entirely) then try adding the `directConnect: true` in your protractor.conf.js

> Git and other tools, often use the git: protocol for accessing files
>   in remote repositories. Some firewall configurations are blocking
>   git:// URLs, which leads to errors when trying to clone repositories
>   or download dependencies. (For example corporate firewalls are
>   "notorious" for blocking git:.)
>
> If you run into this issue, you can force the use of https: instead,
>   by running the following command: git config --global
>   url."https://".insteadOf git://

(see [Common Issues](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/) on Angular tutorial)